Mongodb operator creating multiple replica sets
Following the install instructions on Mongo's github page I have installed the mongoDBcommunity operator using helm. I then deployed a replica set using kubectl apply and the given .yaml file as described here https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/README.md.
The operator appears to be making multiple replica sets. This is unnecessary and wastes compute resources. As I understand after installing the operator using helm you should be able to create a single replica set and then instances within that replica set not create multiple replica sets.
I tried scaling back the instances of the replica set to 1 but that didn't resolve the problem.
I did update the EKS cluster using AWS' standard updater which may have created this issue but I am not certain on that.
